# Soql how to get quotelineitems related to opportunity

Tags: soql, quote

I want to fetch all the quotelineitem items related to an opportunity.
Also, when we make a inner soql (eg.  Select id, (select ID from contacts) from account)  here if we want contacts of a particular then we can write accountRec.contacts. but if we make (select id, (select id from quotelineitems) from quote) can we get a particular  quoteRec's quotelineitems by writing this - quoteRec.quotelineitems??

Comment: Not celar what is quoteRec.quotelineitems, but you can get the quotelineitems for specific opportunity, simply by: select id, (select id from quotelineitems) from quote where OpportunityId = 'myOppId'

Comment: Okay I got quotes and quotelineitems together. So from here, how do I fetch quotelineitem of a quote separately

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have mentioned a couple of non-standard objects (quote, quotelineitem) so I assume that you are dealing with managed packages or an otherwise customized schema, thus nobody will be able to answer your question without further details

Comment: @RenegadeCoder Quote and QuoteLineItem are standard objects.

Comment: @DavidReed I didn't see them in any of my orgs, but I had forgotten that those particular "standard" objects only exist if you enable them in the org settings

Answer (score 0):

We can list out QuoteLineItems by Quote:

```
List<Quote> quos = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote];

for(Quote quo : quos){
    for(QuoteLineItem qli : quo.QuoteLineItems){
        system.debug(qli.Id);
    }
}
```

Worthy if mentioning is that you are not given the names of QuoteLineItems, as these names are the Products' names, which every QuoteLineItem refers to via lookup. You'd do it this way:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

oppIds.addAll(opps.keySet());

List<Quote> quos = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId=: oppIds];

for(Quote quo : quos){
    for(QuoteLineItem qli : quo.QuoteLineItems){
        system.debug(qli.Product2.Name);
    }
}
```

If you want to get all related QuoteLineItems to Opportunities:

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Opportunity opp : opps){
    oppIds.add(opp.id);
}

List<Quote> quos = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId=: oppIds];

for(Quote quo : quos){
    for(QuoteLineItem qli : quo.QuoteLineItems){
        system.debug(qli.Id);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

oppIds.addAll(opps.keySet());

List<Quote> quos = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId=: oppIds];

for(Quote quo : quos){
    for(QuoteLineItem qli : quo.QuoteLineItems){
        system.debug(qli.Id);
    }
}
```